# Получение списка видео с определённого yotube канала

Tags: python

Возникла проблема в получении видео с ютуб канала: https://www.youtube.com/@playapex
Сложность заключается в том что ссылка, а точнее её часть - @playapex, никак не описывается в API и этого нельзя считать не id и не username, в этом и сложность, я не понимаю какой стоит сделать get запрос что бы получить нужные мне данные (список видео, можно и сразу самое последнее, то есть самое свежее). По сути это создано для того что бы я могу получать новые видео с этого канала и оповещать людей в дискорд.

Comment: Вообще, https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues/6247 .

Comment: Спасибо, но вообще пришлось самому через get запросы получать это дело.